# Mysql Left Join is correct?

Tags: mysql

This is my code for Mysql LEFT join.
 it is displaying all values.
 i just want to confirm its correct its displaying all the values of the 2 tables

```
<?php

//connect database 
$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

// select database 

mysql_select_db("mysql joins",$con) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT orders.o_id, persons.p_id ".
"FROM persons ".
```

"LEFT JOIN orders ".
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

```
// print out the contents of each row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['o_id']. " - ". $row['p_id'];
echo "<br />";
}
      ?>
```

Some guy in facebook said its wrong I asked him how can it display values then if its wrong

```
   IT displays --1 - 1 
                 2 - 2 the column values.
```

I want to know it cause mysql joins make the shopping cart complete .

Comment: there is no left join in your code

Comment: yes i forgot this is after the FROM PERSONS " $query= "SELECT persons.lastname, persons.firstname, orders.orderno ". 
"FROM persons ".
"RIGHT JOIN orders ".
"ON orders.o_id = persons.p_id ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());"

Comment: and inner join is fine too $query= "SELECT persons.lastname, persons.firstname, orders.orderno ". 
"FROM persons ".
"INNER JOIN orders ".
"ON orders.o_id = persons.p_id ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// prints out the contents
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo $row['firstname']. " - ". $row['lastname'];
 echo "<br />";
}

Comment: @varunriat Update your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join condition is `orders.o_id = persons.p_id` without knowing the data model this is only a guess but I would assume that o_id is a unique id of an order and p_id an unique id of a person. So two totally different "things". In case there is an order with `o_id = 1` and also a person with `p_id = 1` your join would give you an result this o_id and p_id are equal **BUT** you compare is logically false.

You may have a field like `orders.person_id` (or something similar) than the join would be:
  `WHERE orders.person_id = persons.p_id`

Beside this there is no left join in your sql statement. With the above assumption a left join would be:

```
SELECT 
orders.o_id, persons.p_id 
FROM orders 
left join  persons on orders.person_id = persons.p_id
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no left join in your code

a left join looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT orders.o_id, persons.p_id FROM orders left join  persons  on orders.o_id = persons.p_id ";
```